# I am receiving the following error - The definition of object x has changed since it was compiled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

One of my clients have been receiving this error that is causing issues in their process. Basically, they are thinking the error is related to replication of stored procedures that they assume I messed up. I had to drop some stored procedures that was part of replication and in order to do that I had to remove them from replication and I did generate a new snapshot for synchronizing with the subscriber and it was from then on they saw this error popping up in one of their stored procedures which happened during the same day, but then later on Sunday it happened again for other stored procedures. Now, my question is this related to replication or there is something else to it. Client already mentioned that they did not make any changes at their end.

Comment: Nobody will know know for sure if this related to replication unless you provide more information.  Is the store procedure related to replication? Is it happening on multiple stored procedure or just one?  Look at sys.objects and check created/modified date.

Comment: Look at the created date on the stored procedures' properties--see if that date matches up with the time the errors occurred.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide - It is part of replication and so are the other stored procedures. It is also happening on other stored procedures as well. I will look into sys.objects and check the details.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide - Looked at the date and I see the modified date changed but it was due to the fact that they had to recompile the stored procedure but it does not give me any details on why would it throw an error in the first place.

Comment: Compiling an stored procedure does not change the modified date. Altering definition does. Somehow the object definition is being modified during execution.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide - Yes you are right. I verified with the team and they said that they actually altered the stored procedure in order to fix the issue. Are there any other pointers as to what would have caused it to throw such an error on the publisher side.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying my answer based on the comment by @sepupic. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

This error is generated if stored procedure definition changes while it is running.

Comment: Modifying "any object referenced in the stored procedure" is not the same as modifying stored procedure definition. The error above is caused by modifying the text of sp, not by "changing o dropping the index" which yes can invalidate the plan and cause statement recompile, but NOT cause the error above. The error tells about the object that was COMPILED and changed, so it says about **module**, not about table, index, ecc, referenced by module